# Is this a bug or is this a normal response - dashes in 5 digit-long address results

Tags: here-api, here-autocomplete

I'm using the here.com autocomplete api:

https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=42.812151,-84.510501&in=countryCode:USA,CAN&apiKey=API_KEY&q=23445%20r

And I'm getting dashes in some - not all - 5-digit house numbers:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "2344-5 Riverview Dr, Southfield, MI 48034, United States",
            "id": "here:af:streetsection:lKaIdqmYJgoRR7qRaZkzbC:EAIaBjIzNDQtNShk",
            "resultType": "houseNumber",
            "houseNumberType": "interpolated",
            "address": {
                "label": "2344-5 Riverview Dr, Southfield, MI 48034, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "state": "Michigan",
                "county": "Oakland",
                "city": "Southfield",
                "street": "Riverview Dr",
                "postalCode": "48034",
                "houseNumber": "2344-5"
            },
...
```

**Is this a proper/valid result? Am I missing an implementation note about ignoring dashes in house numbers?**

I realize in some areas a dash is normal in a house number, but this particular address - and others I have tried - should not have a dash in them. I've checked other address lookup APIs, and am not getting house numbers with dashes.

Comment: You didn't really specify what your problem is, you only stated a fact so far. What's the question?

Comment: I will revise my question title!

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. This is bug for which internal core team is working .we will update you once we will have some feedback.